# Get eye, target and up vectors from view matrix

Tags: vector, matrix, directx, rotation, direct3d

In Direct3D, I'm using the Matrix.LookAtLH function to compute the view matrix.

I am using this for the camera, which I orbit around a target by moving the origin to the target position, rotating, and then moving the origin back to (0,0,0).

This is multiplied to the matrix that was originally computed from LookAtLH.

Is there a way I can, after a few of these operations, decompose the matrix to get the eye position, target position, and up vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options :

- Long and difficult : extract eye, up and lookAt from the new computed matrix
- Easy version : apply your transformations (translation, rotation, translation) to a copy of your eye, up, and lookAt. This way you will get very easily the new vectors.

Answer (score 4):

View matricies are very easy to extract data from. Check out the documentation for the function you used (I've used the documentation for D3DXMatrixLookAtLH):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As you can see towards the bottom of the page, the matrix is internally generated like so:

```
zaxis = normal(At - Eye)
xaxis = normal(cross(Up, zaxis))
yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

 xaxis.x           yaxis.x           zaxis.x          0
 xaxis.y           yaxis.y           zaxis.y          0
 xaxis.z           yaxis.z           zaxis.z          0
-dot(xaxis, eye)  -dot(yaxis, eye)  -dot(zaxis, eye)  1
```

Bear in mind, this is only valid for DirectX; transpose the above matrix when porting the same calculations to OpenGL because the coordinate system in DirectX is backwards to the norm.

Comment: OpenGL coordinate system is not backward! It's DirectX coordinate system that is backward :-P

Comment: True! I was taught by a DirectX programmer, so learned everything backwards. Years on, I learnt that I've been using transposed matrices the whole time...

I've updated the answer, thanks for calling me out on that.

Comment: I know this is old but it's neither forward nor backwards. The fixed function pipeline of OpenGL used column major convention and everything about OpenGL is just downstream from that. The programmable pipeline doesn't care. Direct3D and it's libraries use a row major convention. You can use either as long as you are consistent with your matrix multiplication.